# Hot to edit JSON object output with Jersey & Netbeans?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, glassfish-3

I've got a problem with my RESTful webservice - again :(
Summary:
When I call this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/iOSWebServices/resources/credits/1
```

I get this JSON output:

```
{"id":1,"lastname":null,"firstname":"lalsdaksldlasds"}
```

but I want this JSON output:

### {"creditRequest":{"id":1,"lastname":null,"firstname":"lalsdaksldlasds"}}

Long version:
I am using netbeans, glassfish 3 and jersey 1.9.1 to provide some simple test webservices. the problem is, that all json outputs are missing the class name in the output...

For the example above:
CreditRequest.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "creditRequest")
@XmlType(name = "creditRequestType")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CreditRequest {

    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

CreditRequest.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("credits")
@RequestScoped
public class CreditsResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /** Creates a new instance of CreditsResource */
    public CreditsResource() {
    }

    //OUTPUT AS ABOVE!
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getCreditById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("getCreditById");
        CreditRequest creditRequest = new CreditRequest();
        creditRequest.setId(new Long(1));
        creditRequest.setFirstname("lalsdaksldlasds");
        return Response.ok().entity(creditRequest).build();        
    }
}
```

The jersey user guide explains, how is SHOULD work - a quote...

```
Example 5.14. Keep XML root tag equivalent in JSON mapped JSON notation
    JSONConfiguration.mapped().rootUnwrapping(false).build()
and get the following JSON for our Contact bean:
Example 5.15. XML root tag equivalent kept in JSON using mapped notation
    {"contact":{ "id":"2" 
     ,"name":"Bob"
     ,"addresses":{"street":"Long Street 1"
                        ,"town":"Short Village"}}}
```

To do this I wrote a simple class implementing implements ContextResolver (also in the user guide)

JAXBContextResolver.java //Doesn't seem to work

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = {CreditRequest .class}; //FIXED

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("init");
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(
                JSONConfiguration.mapped().rootUnwrapping(false).build(), types);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        System.out.println("get");
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I start the webservice, the output defined in the JAXBContextResolver's constructor will be written "init" - but 
"get" won't....

In this project netbeans controlls the resources of my webservices - and again is initializes 
JAXBContextResolver when the server started - but there is still no rootUnwrapping :(

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
       <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas? I really don't know why there are no changes in my JSON output :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem last week. I found the solution in the web.xml file. After I removed the following lines:

```
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `JAXBContextResolver.types` array is containing `CreditsResource` where `CreditRequest` class should be.
Although, that would explain why there are no changes in JSON output for CreditRequest, not why "get" message is not being printed...

Comment: True - changed is to CreditRequest but that didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

It's almost like the Provider class is not found. You say that Netbeans controls your resources, but isn't it Glassfish(and ultimately jersey) that scans/loads Resource and Provider classes?  Does Glassfish need any configuration to know where to look? In Tomcat, this property is set in servlet config: "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages".

I tried your example exactly has you have it and rootUnwrapping works with Tomcat 6 and Jersey 1.4, in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the best solution but is solves the problem ...
I wroter a wrapper class for CreditRequest

CreditRequestWrapper

```
@XmlType(name = "creditRequestType")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CreditRequestWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "creditRequest")
    private CreditRequest creditRequest;

    public CreditRequestWrapper() {
    }

    public CreditRequestWrapper(CreditRequest creditRequest) {
        this.creditRequest = creditRequest;
    }

    public CreditRequest getCreditRequest() {
        return creditRequest;
    }

    public void setCreditRequest(CreditRequest creditRequest) {
        this.creditRequest = creditRequest;
    }
}
```

And the @GET in my resource

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCreditById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("getCreditById");
    CreditRequest creditRequest = new CreditRequest();
    creditRequest.setId(new Long(1));
    creditRequest.setFirstname("lalsdaksldlasds");
    return Response.ok().entity(new CreditRequestWrapper(creditRequest)).build();
}
```

Now I get what I wanted...

```
{"creditRequest":{"id":1,"firstname":"lalsdaksldlasds","creditVolume":0.0,"creditRate":0.0}}
```

**But I would really love to know why the hell the official way doesn't work for me -.-**